# Sort array of object in node js?

Tags: arrays, node.js, sorting

i am trying to sort an array based on `publishDate` in `nodejs`. Script work properly for array which have `publishDate` but get issue with those array which don't have `publishDate`. In core js all code work fine but now work in node js when we don't have `publishDate`. I Please see my code below:

Code:

```
const parseDate = date_string => {
    let [y,M,d,h,m,s] = date_string.split(/[- :T]/);
    return new Date(y,parseInt(M)-1,d,h,parseInt(m),s.replace('Z',''));
}

const sortByPublishDate = array => {

    array.sort(function(a, b){
        if (a.publish  && b.publish) {
            return parseDate(a.publish.publishDate) - parseDate(b.publish.publishDate)

        }
        else if (a.hasOwnProperty("publish")) {
            return -1;
        } else if (b.hasOwnProperty("publish")) {
            return 1;            
        } else {
            return 0;

        }    
    } );
    return array;
}

module.exports ={
  sortByPublishDate: sortByPublishDate
}
```

Array:

```
[
    {

        "title": "Example1",
        "publish": {

            "publishDate": "2019-8-30T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    },   

    {

        "title": "Example2"
    },    

    {

        "title": "Example3",
        "publish": {           
            "publishDate": "2019-6-30T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    },

    {

        "title": "Example4"
    },    

    {

        "title": "Example5",
        "publish": {           
            "publishDate": "2019-10-25T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    }
    {

        "title": "Example6"
    }
]
```

Expected Output:  Example3, Example1, Example5, Example2, Example4, Example6

Answer (score 0):

Try to add checking of existence property `publish.publishDate` before sorting:

```
if (a.publish && a.publish.publishDate  && b.publish && b.publish.publishDate) 
{
        return parseDate(a.publish.publishDate) - parseDate(b.publish.publishDate);
}
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
  {
"title": "Example1",
"publish": {

  "publishDate": "2019-8-30T12:25:47.938Z",
}
  },
  {

"title": "Example2"
  },
  {
"title": "Example3",
"publish": {
  "publishDate": "2019-6-30T12:25:47.938Z",
}
  },
  {

"title": "Example4"
  },
  {
"title": "Example5",
"publish": {
  "publishDate": "2019-10-25T12:25:47.938Z",
}
  },
  {

"title": "Example6"
  }
];

const parseDate = date_string => {
  let [y, M, d, h, m, s] = date_string.split(/[- :T]/);
  return new Date(y, parseInt(M) - 1, d, h, parseInt(m), s.replace('Z', ''));
}

const sortByPublishDate = array => {

  array.sort(function (a, b) {
if (a.publish && a.publish.publishDate && b.publish && b.publish.publishDate) {
  return parseDate(a.publish.publishDate) - parseDate(b.publish.publishDate)

}
else if (a.publish) {
  return -1;
} else if (b.publish) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 0;

}
  });
  return array;
}

console.log(sortByPublishDate(arr))
```